# PdfPCell text horizontal alignment center - iText5 Java

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation, cell

I am trying to generate report using iText Java. I could not able to align my text content into center it always aligned into left. My code sample is,

```
PdfPTable report= new PdfPTable(1); 
PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(); 
pdfCell.addElement(new Paragraph("key")); 
pdfCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER); 
report.addCell(pdfCell);
```

Also tried with chunk, this also returned left alignment.

```
PdfPTable report= new PdfPTable(1); 
PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(); 

Chunk contentChunk = new Chunk("key");
Paragraph para = new Paragraph(contentChunk);
pdfCell.addElement(para );

pdfCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER); 
report.addCell(pdfCell);
```

Can you help on this?

[image: PdfPCell Alignment]

Answer (score 0):

You can go with following approach:

```
PdfPCell pdfPCell = new PdfPCell();
pdfPCell.setPhrase(new Phrase(title);
pdfPCell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
pdfPCell.setHorizontalAlignment(1);
pdfPCell.setVerticalAlignment(1);
table.addCell(pdfPCell);
```